# Laravel 5.6 moving registration form to modal popup

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to tie in a front end HTML template with a backend Laravel app. I'm trying to move the default Registration and Login form into the templates modal popup registration/login form.

The login part works as intended without modification to the original controller or routing.

However, the registration seems to be mostly working other than it sometimes redirects to `example.com/path` after registering and it shows a

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

The weird thing is that it sometimes lets me register, then stops working other times.

**RegistersUsers.php**

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

trait RegistersUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers;


    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }


    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
                        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }

    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**RegisterController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Jrean\UserVerification\Traits\VerifiesUsers;
use Jrean\UserVerification\Facades\UserVerification;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use MetaTag;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    use RegistersUsers;
    use VerifiesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }

    protected function redirectTo() {
        return '/path';
    }


    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        MetaTag::set('title', __("Register"));
        session()->put('from', request('redirect')?:url()->previous());

        return view('auth.register');
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        $user = $this->create($request->all());

        event(new Registered($user));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        $user->username = $request->get('name');
        $user->save();

        UserVerification::generate($user);

        UserVerification::send($user, __('Welcome and Email Verification'));

        $user->assignRole('member'); //make a member

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect(session()->pull('from',$this->redirectPath()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices here:

1. If you want to use the default behavior (=redirecting after having registered), you can change the return value of the function `redirectPath` to the appropriate path.
2. If you want another behavior (like returning json...) you can change the content of the function `registered`.

   Just note that depending on your return value, there will be different behaviors :

   - If you return a value that is `true` when casting to boolean : that will considered as the response.
   - If you return a value that is `false` when casting to boolean : that will **not** be considered as the response, and laravel will fallback to redirecting with the value of the `redirectPath` function (like in 1.).

   This behavior can be useful if you want to do something once the user is registered but still use the default redirection.

Comment: I don't think that the problem is with the redirect. The registration and redirect works properly using the original registration form (from the original Laravel app). Or does the form location determine the redirect? Cause one is on the page example.com/register, while the other is within a modal box (accessed at any time from the header nav.

Comment: I don't have a need to redirect to something special. Just simply register and return to the homepage.